# How can I convert my Json object to a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an asynchronous function that returns remote json and stores it in a variable. After that, I try to use JSON.stringify on that variable and display the contents in an alert message to make sure they're a string instead of [object].[object],[object]. Here's the code:

```
    Jsonvar = result.shows; 
    var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(Jsonvar)
    alert(jsonstr + "yay");
```

It's not displaying anything. If you need even more code let me know.
If you have another method to convert the object to a string, let me know.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no, is the code above supposed to work?

Comment: var json={data:"data"};var str=JSON.stringify(json.data);console.log(str); code works... just check is ther a shows elementt in json... if it is json Array use the index value and select the show like json[1].shows

Comment: Supposing the code is running at all, the only things I can see that would cause it to fail would be that `result` is `null` or `undefined` or `JSON` is `null` or `undefined`. The latter condition might occur if your browser is old. When the former condition can occur depends on how `result` is retrieved. Nevertheless, if there's no errors, I'd look into whether the code is running at all.

Comment: JSON *is* text (or, "a string"). Thus there is no "JSON Object" although there is (presumably) a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.stringify(JSON_OBJECT)` will convert a **valid JSON object** to string.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s97QX/) - check this example

Note : verify if result.shows is a valid JSON object.

Comment: That's true, but they're already calling `JSON.stringify` in their code. Perhaps you could clarify why, specifically, it isn't working?

Comment: @icktoofay - you would have missed to read this - " valid JSON object". So, "result.shows" must be a valid JSON object.

Comment: If it's not a JSON-serializable object, what would it be? A function? I doubt it's a function, and most other things *are* valid JSON-serializable objects.

Comment: Yeah. or may be "result.shows" is "undefined". Because "null" will display as string. only undefined is not. It will display as a blank.

Comment: Suppose it were `undefined`. You would get `undefined` out, not a blank. [Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/sCabX/)

Comment: I use Firefox latest version. For me it shows blank alert message, not "undefined". :)

Comment: Fair enough, but when you concatenate it with `'yay'`, as in the question, you'll get `undefinedyay` in all browsers. [Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/mWdW2/)

Comment: Yeah. of course, string concatenation will do so :)

Comment: I keep getting [object object],[object object] etc in the alert message

Comment: @Brandon what is your browser and its version?

Comment: @vivek_nk here's a fiddle demonstrating the json returned http://jsfiddle.net/xLYNV/3/ var objf = dataf.contents; is the variable storing the json in the getStuff function. I've also appended the json to a ul element so you can see the format.